# Remove Input data

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to remove the tag containing the data on the click of cross button.

Here I just want that when I click on the "remove-glyphicon" tag, then the tag should be removed.

```js
function toggleCloseColor(a) {
  var opacity = a.css("opacity");
  opacity = opacity < .8 ? 1 : .6;
  a.css({
    opacity: opacity
  });
}

${document}.ready(function() {
  ${".tag a"}.each(toggleCloseColor);
});
```

```css
.tag.md {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.tag {
  padding: .3em .4em .4em;
  margin: 0 .1em;
  float: left;
}
.tag a {
  color: #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .5;
}
.tag .remove {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  top: 0;
}
.tag a {
  margin: 0 0 0 .3em;
}
.glyphicon-white {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="tag label btn-info md">
  <span>com.example.ExampleSuite</span>
  <a style="opacity: 0.6;">
    <i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

I have tried a lot in javascript through the help of creating a function but I am unable to remove this tag by clicking "remove-glyphone"

Comment: Instead of sharing snapshot, share the fiddle link.

Comment: This is fiddle link     
http://jsfiddle.net/7zkCU/30/

Comment: Just set a flag on click of `x` and in render, use `{ !flag ? <button JSX> : null }`

Comment: Where is the javascript? You need to handle the click event.

Comment: yes, exactly but i am not getting it how to do that

Comment: `$(".tag a").click(function(){$(this).parent().remove()});` That's all.

Comment: Unless this is some weird library syntax I don't know: You are using `{}` instead of `()` for JQuery code. And you're not actually including JQuery to begin with.

Comment: Some of the code should be omitted for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for what you're doing. No jQuery involved. Took the code from your fiddle for people to see.

```
<script>
  function remove(elem) {
    elem.parentElement.remove();
  }
</script>

<br/>
Tags:
<span class="tag label label-info">
  <span>Example Tag </span>
  <a onClick="remove(this)"><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a>
</span>
```

You want to pass the element to the function which is probably the easiest way, otherwise you can set up event listeners to handle button presses.